# Handling elasticsearch exception

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Im using python elastic search module and need to handle exception.

```
try:
    es.index(index='tickets', doc_type='tickets', body=doc)
except es.ElasticsearchException as es1:
    print 'error'
```

but I get this error -

```
AttributeError: 'Elasticsearch' object has no attribute 'ElasticsearchException'
```

Comment: didn't get a chance too try but think it should be `except elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException as es1` and not `es.ElasticsearchException`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the error points out `ElasticsearchException` is not an attribute of `Elasticsearch` object . 
From the [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/exceptions.html) it is a class in `elasticsearch` module

So the example code should look something on these  lines :

```
import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()
es.index(index='tickets', doc_type='tickets', body=doc)
try :
    es.indices.create(index='test-index', ignore=400)
except elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException as es1:
    print 'error'
```

Comment: This is no longer a relevant solution.  My elasticsearch module does not have a top level attribute ElasticsearchException

Comment: @AaronSoellinger, I have the same issue, could you pls tell me how you solved this problem? Thanks

Comment: `from elasticsearch import ElasticsearchException`  works for me with `elasticsearch==7.8.0`